how to disable a button for a day after a user clicks on it in flutter
Please i'm new to flutter. i want users to be able to withdraw once in a day at any given time but i would want the withdrawal button to be disabled after their first click or first withdrawal then by tomorrow the button will be active. please how can i try this, i have tried using sharedpreferences but to no avail.
i tried this code below but am getting error "FormatException: Invalid date format" also i have tried changing the date format but to no avail. please any help will be so much appreciated.


ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   // var currentTime =  DateTime.now();
   //  var _formatter = DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm').format(currentTime);
   // var resetTime =  DateTime.parse(prefs.getString("time").toString()); 
   // final resetTime = DateTime.parse(prefs.getString("time") ?? '');

    var currentTime =  DateTime.now();
    var resetTime =  DateTime.parse(prefs.getString("time").toString());
    if(resetTime != null && !compareDate(currentTime, resetTime))
                                    prefs.setBool("one_tap", true);
                                  
      if(prefs.getBool("one_tap") == null || prefs.getBool("one_tap")!){
          print("Once in a day");
          title = "Change Date";
          prefs.setBool("one_tap", false);
          prefs.setString("time", currentTime.toString());
         }
},
child: Text(title),),

compareDate(DateTime current, DateTime reset) {
    if (reset != null) {
      return current.year == reset.year &&
          current.month == reset.month &&
          current.day == reset.day;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }


Hi ..Are you using any kind firestore database for this ?  . I would add the date when button pushed to DB .Then  when app opens again retrieve the date then compare it to current data . If the date difference is 24hours make button active .. If not , disable

Nice idea, please how can I achieve that, but see how my app works, when a user clicks on withdrawal button, it sends the users input to paystack after validations and sends back webhook to my admin panel and also debits the user so with this your new idea how can I save the data before sending or pushing users data to paystack for debit

For unabling user to click button in a period of time you can simply use DateTime as you wrote before.
You should save the time in sharedprefrences or other databases when user click on the button and check the current time to the passed time when user click on the button again and for that you can get the passed time like the code bellow:
// get the submit button time and then store it in sharedpref
  DateTime submitButtonTime  = DateTime.now();

  // get the current time when you want to check the passed time
  DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1));

  // you can use "difference" method to get the passed time between two 
  //times
  num passedTime = currentTime.difference(submitButtonTime).inHours;

  // print the passed time in hours, there are other types like  
  //minutes or milliseconds if you want to get more precise to the passed 
  //time
  print(passedTime);


Try that pseudo code, the following code is not guaranteed to be produceable, but gather the idea from it:
just make a method to decide whether the button is enabled or not:
bool makeItEnabled(){

SharedPreferences prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

String? lastClickTime = prefs.getString('lastWithdraw');

if(lastClickTime == null){

    // set that button enabled
    return true;
}

return (DateTime.now().diff(DateTime.parse(lastClickTime).hours > 24 );

}

and in your button:
YouButton(

enabled: makeItEnabled(),
onPressed:()async{

    // make your withdraw
    // store that time in sharedpref
    SharedPreferences prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('lastWithdraw' , DateTime.now());

}
)


There are two options to do that :

When withdrawn is done at that time you have to save that datetime is your backend database, and when user came back to same withdrawn button page that time hit the api to check the last withdrawal datetime and then you can match with your current datetime and if its more than a day then enable the button and vice versa.
Save a bool variable in backend when withdrawal success and in first option we are calculating the remaining time in frontend so now do that in backend and same logic will run and you can enable/disable button using that bool variable


Paystack gateway is slow and users always withdraw more than their balance since I'm listening or waiting for the webhook before debiting the users so sometimes it delays which makes some users to withdraw above their balance since the webhook didn't bounce to the backend so they could be debited as such they will withdraw more than expected amount they have so I wouldn't want to listen to webhook again. .

Please do you have a simple code on how I could get ur first idea done, i guess it will work, am new to flutter please

So once you have set up your project with Firebase Firestore ( https://youtu.be/sz4slPFwEvs?si=O1gYA__1OFOb5KUb ) . The code would look like something like this :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool _isButtonActive = true;
  FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String _collectionName = 'button_activity';
  String _documentId = 'last_pressed';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkButtonStatus();
  }

  Future<void> _checkButtonStatus() async {
    try {
      DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
          await _firestore.collection(_collectionName).doc(_documentId).get();
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        Timestamp lastPressed = documentSnapshot['date'];
        DateTime lastPressedDate = lastPressed.toDate();
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
        Duration difference = currentDate.difference(lastPressedDate);

        setState(() {
          _isButtonActive = difference.inHours >= 24;
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error checking button status: $e");
    }
  }

  Future<void> _handleButtonPress() async {
    try {
      await _firestore.collection(_collectionName).doc(_documentId).set({
        'date': Timestamp.now(),
      });

      setState(() {
        _isButtonActive = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error handling button press: $e");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Firestore Button Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _isButtonActive ? _handleButtonPress : null,
          child: Text('Press me'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

When the app starts it checks the status of button with :
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkButtonStatus();
  }

_checkButtonStatus() checks/retrieves  the date in the firestore db and also checks the time difference . If its equal or more than 24 hours it sets  _isButtonActive  to TRUE
Based on _isButtonActive state, if TRUE it will let user do  _handleButtonPress . if FALSE it will do nothing .
   ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: _isButtonActive ? _handleButtonPress : null,
      child: Text('Press me'),
    ),

Then _handleButtonPress  is part of code where current date gets added to firestore db :
 Future<void> _handleButtonPress() async {
    try {
      await _firestore.collection(_collectionName).doc(_documentId).set({
        'date': Timestamp.now(),
      });

      setState(() {
        _isButtonActive = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error handling button press: $e");
    }
  }

Remember to name your Firestore Collection accordingly . ( Ex 'Users' , and then for document_id you can use the user's UID . Let me know if you still need some help

This worked like a magic bro, exactly what am looking out for. lastly please how can i put action on the button if it is active such as when the user clicks on it when it is active, it will direct the user to another page to process the withdrawal and please also is there a way to put a write up on the inactive button to display a message that "user can make a withdrawal till 24hrs" thanks in advance

below is what i have tried please      ElevatedButton(
child: Text("Button2"),
onPressed: _isButtonActive ? _handleButtonPress
? () {
// to direct them to another page or API
                  }
                : null),  but am gettting error "Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'.

Try changing the condition."
